# jQuery animate is changing text / not animating background

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, jquery-animate

we have a page that displays an animation for our header/ buttons users use to navigate the page.

The problem we are having is that the buttons when being hovered over by the mouse are not changing the background but it is changing the colour of the text.

What we want is the text to be white and the button itself to match the colour of the header / subNav2

the jQuery.

```
function headerChange($stopOnColor) {
    //remove all classes at start
    $('#siteNav').removeClass('change195369 changeBEBD80 change708D81 change70547A changeD49A4B');
    $('.subNav2 a').removeClass('change195369 changeBEBD80 change708D81 change70547A changeD49A4B');
    $('.subNav h1 a').removeClass('change195369 changeBEBD80 change708D81 change70547A changeD49A4B');

    $colBlue = '#195369'; //rbga(25, 83, 105, 0.8)
    $colMustard = '#BEBD80'; //rbga(190, 189, 128, 0.8)
    $colDirtyGreen = '#708D81'; //rbga(112, 141, 129, 0.8)
    $colPurple = '#70547A'; //rbga(112, 84, 122, 0.8)
    $colOrange = '#D49A4B'; //rbga(212, 154, 75, 0.8)
    var colorArray = [$colBlue, $colMustard, $colDirtyGreen, $colPurple, $colOrange];

    if (!$stopOnColor){
        colorArray.reverse();
        var interval = setInterval(function(){ 
            if(colorArray.length == 0){
                clearInterval(interval);
                return;
            }
            var entry = colorArray.pop();
            var oldstr = entry;
            var str = oldstr;
            str = /#(.+)/.exec(str)[1];

            $('header#header-top').animate({"background-color": entry}, 1000, function(){
                $('#siteNav').addClass('change' + str);
                //$('.navbar #siteNav .nav li.active a').animate({"color": $stopOnColor}, 1000);
                //$('.subNav2 a').addClass('change' + str);
                $('.subNav2 a').animate({"color": entry}, 1000);
                //$('.subNav h1 a').addClass('change' + str);
                $('.subNav h1 a').animate({"color": entry}, 1000);
                if (colorArray.length == 0){
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        headerChange();
                    }, 5000);
                }
            });
            $('.subNav2 a').animate({"color": entry}, 1000);
            $('.subNav h1 a').animate({"color": entry}, 1000, function(){
//                $(this).addClass('change' + str);
            //to do, fix override for color on hover. 
            });

        }, 5000);
    }
    else {
        var oldstr = $stopOnColor;
        var str = oldstr;
        str = /#(.+)/.exec(str)[1];

        $('header#header-top').animate({"background-color": $stopOnColor}, 1000);
        $('.navbar #siteNav .nav > .active > a').animate({"color": $stopOnColor}, 1000);
        $('.subNav2 a').addClass();
        $('.subNav h1 a').addClass('change' + str);
        $('#siteNav').addClass('change' + str);
    }
};
```

CSS

```
.subNav a {
    color: #353535;
    background: none;
    text-shadow: none;
    text-shadow: 0;
    border-color: none;
    border: solid;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 5px 12px;
    width: 220px;
    max-width: 220px;
    max-height: 76px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;

}
.subNav a i {
    opacity: 0;
    position: relative;
}
.subNav a i.fa-angle-right {
    left: -15px;
}
.subNav a i.fa-angle-left {
    left: 15px;
}
.subNav a:link, .subNav a:visited, .subNav a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
}  
.subNav a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #353535;
    color: #FFF;
}
.subNav a.change195369 {border-color: #195369; color: #195369;}
.subNav a.change195369:hover {background-color: #195369; color: #FFF;}
.subNav a.changeBEBD80 {border-color: #BEBD80; color: #BEBD80;}
.subNav a.changeBEBD80:hover {background-color: #BEBD80; color: #FFF;}
.subNav a.change708D81 {border-color: #708D81; color: #708D81;}
.subNav a.change708D81:hover {background-color: #708D81; color: #FFF;}
.subNav a.change70547A {border-color: #70547A; color: #70547A;}
.subNav a.change70547A:hover {background-color: #70547A; color: #FFF;}
.subNav a.changeD49A4B {border-color: #D49A4B; color: #D49A4B;}
.subNav a.changeD49A4B:hover {background-color: #D49A4B; color: #FFF;}
```

[image: what it looks like now]   [image: How we want it]

How it is
How we want it

Comment: jQuery cannot animate color, you need a plugin for that as e.g https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color  or better use CSS only solution

Comment: The Header IS being animated. It must have been added in a more recent version as it is most definitely animating colours.

('header#header-top').animate({"background-color": entry}, 1000, function() 

I can't understand why it would be changing the colours on the header if animation never worked?

the CSS property is definitely being animated and is working to an extent, it just seems to be animating the text instead of the background, and if the background is being animated it seems to not turn the text / chevrons white